# Single client with both a static and a DHCP address

Tags: router, ip, dhcp

I used my TP-Link AC1750 (Archer) router to assign a static address to my Brother laser printer, but the router assigned a DHCP address also when I rebooted the router. A network scan has it showing up in BOTH the static address list **AND** the DHCP list.  Best I can tell, it's the DHCP IP address that is functional.

What happened? And how can I fix it? (Mac OSX 10.14)

The static pool is 1-99, DHCP pool 100-254. So I have two network printers (one cabled and the other WiFi), each with two IP addresses. Also have a TP RE450 range extender which shows four IP (DHCP) addresses assigned...

I assume that those are actually clients which are connecting through the range extender.

Comment: How was the static address made? Is the address still part of the shared pool? The trick to static addresses is to assign them via DHCP, but remove them from the shared pool.

Comment: Which tp-link router and what exactly did you do?

Comment: I incorporated your comment's information into the question.

Comment: Thanks Zx485....I'm a first time user here.